# Generic class that implements a particular interface

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

So lets take this example that I have a class A and class B both A and B are implementing a specific interface letters. Now I need to make a specific function in another class wherein I need to pass either A class object or B class object and similarly do some operation on these objects and return either A or B class objects. Now I can define the function using a generic type T but the catch is T must always implement interface letters.
So a Object of class 1 which doesn't implement interface letters wont be allowed to pass this function.

```
public class A implements letters{...}
public class B implements letters{...}
public class LetterOperations{
 public T letterOp(T letter){..}
}
```

Here letterOp() must be accepting only those kind of generic classes T which implement interface letters.

Comment: The Main problem is how to define precisely the generic type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add type parameter bound when declaring generic class:

```
   public class LetterOperations<T extends letter> {
     public T letterOp(T letter){..}
   }
```

Or use method with type parameter:

```
   public <T extends letter> T letterOp(T letter){..}
```